# How to specify a range in nondet (to avoid choicepoints in PL Unit Testing)

Tags: prolog

I wrote some tests for some Prolog codes and got "Test succeeded with choicepoint" warning. Here's one of my tests:

```
test(overlap_intervals):-
    overlap_intervals([0, 10], [5, 15]).
```

Here's the codes:

```
%% precondition: X1<Y1 and X2<Y2
overlap_intervals([X1,Y1], [X2,Y2]):-
    (X1<X2, Y1<Y2, Y1>X2); !,
    (X1>X2, Y1>Y2, Y1<X2).
```

I saw from other posts that I can use "nondet" `test(foo, nondet) :- ....` to avoid choice points, such as:

```
test(member, all(X == [a,b,c])) :-
    member(X, [a,b,c]). % quoting Prolog document
```

However, I'm dealing with intervals in my case. The "nondet" would be a range of numbers, rather than an exhaustible list. For example (which apparently doesn't work but gets my goal across):

```
test(overlap_intervals, all(Y<10, Y>0)):-
    overlap_intervals([0, 10], [Y, 15]).
```

Can someone explain why there are choicepoints and how to avoid them in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a choicepoint because you got confused about precedence when mixing `;` and `!`. As usual in logic, *and* (`,`) binds stronger than *or* (`;`).

Better ways of writing your predicate would be:

```
overlap_intervals_2([X1,Y1], [X2,Y2]):-
    (   (X1<X2, Y1<Y2, Y1>X2),
        !
    ;   (X1>X2, Y1>Y2, Y1<X2) ).
```

or (preferred):

```
overlap_intervals_3([X1,Y1], [X2,Y2]):-
    (X1<X2, Y1<Y2, Y1>X2),
    !.
overlap_intervals_3([X1,Y1], [X2,Y2]):-
    (X1>X2, Y1>Y2, Y1<X2).
```

These alternative definitions make it clearer where the cut belongs, highlighting that it was misplaced in your version. Tests:

```
?- overlap_intervals([0, 10], [5, 15]).
true ;
false.

?- overlap_intervals_2([0, 10], [5, 15]).
true.

?- overlap_intervals_3([0, 10], [5, 15]).
true.
```

Note that none of these definitions cover the case where one interval is contained within another one. I would say that `overlap_intervals([0, 10], [1, 9])` should be true, but the exact meaning of the predicate depends on your application, of course.

As for your use of `all` in a test head, `all(between(0, 10, Y))` should work, I think (not tested).

Comment: Thank you, Isabelle! Switching `;` and `,` did solve the problem. `all(between(0, 10, Y))` doesn't work unfortunately but doesn't matter.